# table not displaying innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display an array of books as a table. This function runs everytime I submit a form adding a new book, but after I do that I still see an empty table.

```
function displayLibrary(myLibrary = [], table) {
  console.log(table);
  table.innerHTML = myLibrary.map((book) => {
    return `
  <tr>
    <td>${book.title}</td> 
    <td>${book.author}</td>
    <td>${book.pages}</td>
    <td>${book.read ? "✔" : "❌"}</td>
  </tr>
    `;
  }).join("");
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(myLibrary.length);`?

Comment: This code looks fine to me, so the problem is probably in the caller.

Comment: What is also the value of `table`? May you share how this function is used?

Comment: sorry somehow the 2nd line of my answers didn't put into that, 
Did you put the returned value inside `table` and `tbody` tag?

could you try return JSON.stringify(table); befor the map function?

Comment: Plz give use the return of this `function displayLibrary(myLibrary = [], table) {console.log(myLibrary, table)}`

Comment: I ran your JS on JS Fiddle and it does work!! I don't think there is any problem in your JS but in HTML or something. Or did you get `table` element in your JS file?  https://jsfiddle.net/b87fh5qy/14/

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#table');

function displayLibrary(lib, elem) {
  lib.forEach(book => {
    let html = `
      <tr>
        <td>${book.title}</td> 
        <td>${book.author}</td>
        <td>${book.pages}</td>
        <td>${book.read ? "✔" : "❌"}</td>
      </tr>
      `;
    elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  });

}

const myLibrary = [{
    title: 'The Hobbit',
    author: 'T',
    pages: 1000,
    read: false
  },
  {
    title: 'Harry Potter',
    author: 'JKR',
    pages: 400,
    read: true
  }
]

displayLibrary(myLibrary, table);
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```